# Миграция пользователей из AD Win2008R2 Server на Zentyal 4.2 без репликации

Tags: linux, samba, active-directory

Необходимо перенести AD небольшой конторы с Windows на Linux. С предыдущей нужны только Пользователи (логин, пароль, UID, SID), чтобы при подключении к новому домену, локальный профиль пользователя остался прежним. Разнообразных эксчейнджей на сервере нет, профили не перемещаемые. Подскажите?

Answer (score 1):

1. Подключаем samba как домен http://www.samba4.ru/?p=246
2. Передаем ей управление  http://www.samba4.ru/?p=259

Либо документация к samba может помочь раздел
Join the existing domain as a Domain Controller
https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Join_an_additional_Samba_DC_to_an_existing_Active_Directory

Comment: Еще есть samba tool есть vampire vampire [options] domain
       Join and synchronise a remote AD domain to the local server. Please
       note that samba-tool vampire is deprecated, please use samba-tool
       domain join instead.

Comment: но это же простая миграция и наследуются абсолютно все настройки, нет?